# Python property getter and setter similar method names

Tags: python, properties

I have a couple of questions regarding @property decorator usage:

1. How does it work with the same getter and setter method names?
   As far as I know @property decorator is a syntactic sugar for this construction:

```
class car:
     def __init__(self):
         self._color = ""
     
     #@property   
     def color(self):
         return self._color
     
     color = property(color)
```

But if I want to add a setter method for the "color" property with the same name I can't do it like this:

```
class car:
     def __init__(self):
         self._color = ""
     
     #@property   
     def color(self):
         return self._color
     
     color = property(color)
     
     #@color.setter    
     def color(self, color): #This method rewrites the "color" property
         self._color = color
     
     color = color.setter(color) #This doesn't work, because now "color" is the method
```

How does magic @color.setter decorator work in this case?

2. The second question is about internal structure of the "property" descriptor. As far as I remember, the "property" class is written in C, but by this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#abstract)  there is a pure Python "property" implementation example. The question is why the methods-decorators getter, setter, deleter are implemented this way:

```
def setter(self, fset):
         prop = type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)
         prop._name = self._name
         return prop
```

Why the new instance of the "property" class was created ? Why we can't just redefine the fset method and return the same instance of the "property" class like this?

```
def setter(self, fset):
     self.fset = fset
     return self
```

Comment: Just don't rebind `color` when you trying to write the equivalent code for the setter. It's not like `color.setter` cares what the name of the variable that holds its argument is.

Comment: Right but the question is precisely understanding the syntactic sugar. What's the python equivalent without it? Clearly it doesn't rebind `color` even though based on how the syntactic sugar is commonly explained, it would. PEP 318 states that it would not do an intermediate assignment of `color`. But the question is how?

Answer (score 0):

Every decorated function creation in the class body does the following:

1. create a function object with the function's signature and content
2. call the decorator with this function object as argument
3. assign the returned value from the decorator to the identifier with the function's name within the class' namespace

So calling `@x.setter` for property `x` with decorated `def x` means that `x` gets overwritten, but the result of the call is again a property that carries over the state of the original property `x`. If you call instead `@x.setter` for property `x` with decorated `def y`, the identifier `y` is created with the result, which is again a property carrying the state of property `x`, but a separate instance.

The following is a (pretty hypothetical) example:

```py
class A:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._truth = 0
        
    @property
    def truth(self):
        return self._truth
    
    @truth.setter
    def truth(self, val):
        self._truth = val
        
    @truth.setter
    def truth_positive(self, val):
        self._truth = max(0, val)
```

So `truth` and `truth_positive` have the same getter, but different setters. If the setter implementation would modify the current property instance instead of creating a new one, this would not be possible. The original setter would be replaced by the latest.